# error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers when trying to put it in a Card title line 18

Tags: android, flutter

so it doesn't let me use name in the title of the card and I have already tried setting name as a static variable however I still get thrown an error when building.
I have listed all the relevant lines of code with //
Thank you very much for the help

I should add when I tried setting name as static var name = "" and then running the app the card name still comes out as blank so therefore it isn't updating the static variable. Why so? Is there a way to work around it? How do I do so?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';


class CardApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardAppState createState() => _CardAppState();
}

class _CardAppState extends State<CardApp> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<CardApp> {
  var _widgetsList  = [];
  final myController = new TextEditingController();
  var name ;
  var test =
  Card(
    child: new ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.album),
      title: Text(name), //this line
      subtitle: Text('this is the subtitle'),
    ),
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              return Alert(
                context: context,
                title: 'Please Input your note',
                desc: 'this is where you will input your note',
                buttons: [
                  DialogButton(child: Text('Cancel'), onPressed:() {Navigator.pop(context);}),
                  DialogButton(child: Text('Confirm'), onPressed:() => setState(() //this line
                  {name = myController.text; // all of this
                  print(name);
                  _widgetsList.add(test);
                  Navigator.pop(context);}
                  )
//end
                  )
                ],
                content: Form(child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: myController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Input what you want to say'),
                    )
                  ],
                ))
              ).show();
            }
          ),
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
            title: Text('The Note App', style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white
            ),),
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Card(
                  child: new ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.album),
                    title: Text('hello'),
                    subtitle: Text('hi'),
                  ),
                ),
                ..._widgetsList, // cards get appended to _widgetlist so it appears up on the screen
              ],

            ),





          ),

        ),

    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution instead of using a variable to be a card I made a function called addCard to append to my widgetlist

```dart
addCard(){
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.album),
        title: Text(name),
        subtitle: Text('hi'),
      ),
    );
  }
```